# AppceleratorStudio unable to write to install directory

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-studio

I wanted to play with Hyperloop lately so I tried to pull latest SDK from command line. While trying to do that I got messages that `/Users/my_user/.appcelerator/install` is not writeable and told me to run the following commands:

```
sudo chown -R my_user /Users/my_user/.appcelerator/install
chmod -R 0700 /Users/my_user/.appcelerator/install
```

now when I try to start Appcelerator Studio I get the same message. not that I have a problem running the command - but why does it keep repeating itself?

**Edit**

after running those command Studio still not loading and showing that message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by running the following command in terminal:

```
sudo chown -Rv [USERNAME] /Users/[USERNAME]
```

Comment: Perhaps at some point you have run Studio or `appc setup` as sudo, mixing up the permissions as such.

Comment: @FokkeZandbergen just learned that running stuff in sudo (although sometimes inevitable) can cause problems.